# Contracts interaction issue

Tags: solidity, remix

I got stuck in making two contracts interact. The code for two contracts is as follows:

`Test1.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract Test1 {

   struct Car {
       string carCreationDate;
       string carOrigin;
       address carOwner;
   }

   mapping(uint => Car) public CarStruct;

   function setNewCar(string memory _carCreationDate, string memory _carOrigin, address _carOwner) public returns(uint) {
       uint carId = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, now)));
       CarStruct[carId].carCreationDate = _carCreationDate;
       CarStruct[carId].carOrigin = _carOrigin;
       CarStruct[carId].carOwner = _carOwner;
       return carId;
   }
}
```

`Test2.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
import "./Test1.sol";

contract Test2 {

    Test1 test1;
    function carAdd(string memory _carCreationDate, string memory _carOrigin, address _carOwner) public returns(uint) {
        uint carId = test1.setNewCar(_carCreationDate, _carOrigin, _carOwner);
        return (carId);
    }
}
```

There are no issues deploying the contracts, however when I try to implement `carAdd` function in `Test2.sol`, Remix gives me an error and I don't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Where do you instantiate `test1` variable? Are you creating a new `Test1` instance or referencing an existing one? There's no code for that given.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, what I'm trying is to reference contract Test1 with this line:
'Test1 test1;". I'm not sure if it's the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your contract `Test1`. You are currently only using a variable `test1` which is of type `Test1` but it's not instantiated anywhere.

You have two options for creating a proper instance: use an existing one (you need to know the contract's address) or create a new one. At least for testing I suggest you just create a new one.

So change your code to be (move the instance inside the function):

```
function carAdd(string memory _carCreationDate, string memory _carOrigin, address _carOwner) public returns(uint) {
    Test1 test1 = new Test1();
    uint carId = test1.setNewCar(_carCreationDate, _carOrigin, _carOwner);
    return (carId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that totally works! I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what is wrong